# Combining installers into one installer [Language unspecific]

Tags: installation, bundle

I've got a question about installers.

At my workplace we have a development environment which envelops quite a lot of IDE's and plugins for those IDE's.

I've just started working there and I have yet to set up my development environment. However keeping in mind that they will hire new Juniors within the next couple of months I thought it might be a good idea to create an installer that calls all other installers, essentially making an installation bundle of IDE's.

Now here's the catch. I know it should be possible with visual studio but I can only get my hands on the Express edition, and I doubt they will get a professional edition just for me.

**So my question is, how do I create such a bundle installation?** I can work in virtually any environment but at work we have Eclipse and at home I've got VS Professional (but no access to the files I need).

Any help is welcome, Rope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are interest in a free powerful tool the only one I can recommend is Wix, and its new feature called [Burn, used to handled installation package bundles](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm). There are payed tools that can help you get this done much faster, but you'll need a little budget for that.